# I just updated my Android Studio to 2.3.1. I am getting the following error

Tags: android, android-studio

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 25.3.0, 25.1.1, 23.4.0. Examples include
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.0 and
>   com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.1 less... (Ctrl+F1)  There are
>   some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are
>   incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is
>   compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not
>   the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your
>   targetSdkVersion.)

[image]

Comment: `All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version` is your answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification)

Comment: Adding images correctly

Answer (score -1):

Go to all the gradle files and make version identical.
It should be having same version across all modules as tagetVersionSDK.
Hopefully This should solve your problem.